# psake set execution directory

Tags: powershell, working-directory, psake

I’m trying to move form MSBuild to psake.

My repository structure looks like this:

```
.build
 | buildscript.ps1
.tools
packages
MyProject
MyProject.Testing
MyProject.sln
```

I want to clean the repository before building (using git clean -xdf).
But I can’t find a way (expect with the .Net classes) to set the execution directory of git.

First I searched for a way to set the working directory in psakes exec:

```
exec { git clean -xdf }
exec { Set-Location $root
       git clean -xdf }
```

Set-Location works but after the exec block is finished the location is still set to $root.

Then I tried:

```
Start-Process git -Argumentlist "clean -xdf" -WorkingDirectory $root
```

Which works but keeps git open and no future task gets executed.

How can I execute git in $root?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've encountered the same exact problem as yours in psake with my build scripts. The "Set-Location" cmdlet doesn't affect the Win32 working directory for your Powershell session.

Here is an example:

```
# Start a new PS session at "C:\Windows\system32"
Set-Location C:\temp
"PS Location = $(Get-Location)"
"CurrentDirectory = $([Environment]::CurrentDirectory)"
```

The output will be:

```
PS Location = C:\temp
CurrentDirectory = C:\Windows\system32
```

What you probably need to do is change the Win32 current directory before invoking native commands such as "git":

```
$root = "C:\Temp"
exec {
  # remember previous directory so we can restore it at end
  $prev = [Environment]::CurrentDirectory
  [Environment]::CurrentDirectory = $root

  git clean -xdf

  # you might need try/finally in case of exceptions...
  [Environment]::CurrentDirectory = $prev
}
```